# How to skip current iteration of loop if condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to skip if

```
x.configured === true
```

is false.
My code(works fine)

```
for (let i = 0; i < appids.length; i++) {
    let appid = appids[i];
    const endpointurl = baseurl + appid + '/branches'
    setTimeout(() => {
        fetch(endpointurl, {
            headers: { Authorization: token }
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                    console.log('appid ' + appid + ' has ' + data.filter(x => x.configured === true).length + ' configured branches');
                }
            });
    }, i * 1000);

}
```

I would like to skip if

```
x => x.configured === false
```

The problem is loop already finished the job.

How to refactor it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There's nothing to skip when you first hit `x.configured === true` because at that point the loop has already finished its job.

Comment: @Andreas Well that is the problem . My bad. Is there any simple way how I could check before the loop finishes the job? Continue comes to my mind, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: _"Is there any simple way how I could check before the loop finishes the job? Continue comes to my mind"_ - There's no loop anymore when you have something to compare. So -> No. Search on SO on how to execute Promises (`fetch()`) in sequence. That way you can skip an id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip one iteration use the "continue" keyword or the "break" if you want to stop the loop. Check this page for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

But in your code you're already filtering "x.configured === true", the "x => x.configured === false" is already skipped

Comment: The first `fetch()` is executed _after_ the loop. There's nothing to `break` out of or `continue`